# Chose random a word from txt file and mark it as chosen in C

Tags: c

I want to randomly extract a word from the text file and mark it as chosen.(I want to add a * at the end of the word)
I can extract the words random but when I want to mark the word as chosen (add '*') the * character is added at the end of the file and not at the end of the chosen word. I don't know why.
Does anyone have an idea?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
char secret[50];
    unsigned long fileLen;
    srand(time(NULL));

        FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "a+");
        if( fp == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "No such file or directory: %s\n");
            return 1;
        }

    //Get file length
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        fileLen=ftell(fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf("fileLen --------->%ld\n", fileLen);

    do{

        // generate random number between 0 and filesize
        unsigned long random = (rand() % fileLen) + 1;

        // seek to the random position of file
        fseek(fp, random, SEEK_SET);
        // get next word in row ;)

        printf("Random ------->%ld\n", random);//testing purpose
        printf("ftell --------->%ld\n", ftell(fp));

        int result = fscanf(fp, "%*s %s", secret);
        printf("Chosen word is: %s \n", secret);

        int len = strlen(secret);
        if(result)
            {
                fseek(fp, len, SEEK_CUR);
                fputc('*', fp); // put a '*' at the end of the word that was chosen
            }

        if( result != 0 )
            break;
    } while(1);

fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: In general - you cannot append characters in a middle of a file. In such a cases you just recreate a new file and save it in place of the old one.

Comment: I need to mark direct in file the chosen words. It is not allowed to create another extra txt file.

Comment: Then you can't do that  What you can perhaps, is to reserve a space for each word in a file - like extra whitespace or something, which you can overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Using `fseek` to get the length is good, and logically, it stops at the end of the file, the issue is that is stays there (that's why * is in the end), so after using it, you are at the end of the file, use `rewind(fp)` to return to the beginning of the file after using `fseek(fp)` to get its length.

Also, read Eugene Sh's comment.

Comment: I found the issue. the file was opened in a+ mode and therefore the character was added at the end of the file. I corrected the open mode in r+ and now it is working. I can add a * at the end of the words in file (one word per line) but the first letter from the next word is deleted. I don't find the reason. I tried this : if(result)
            {
                fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR);
                fputc('*', fp); // put a '*' at the end of the word that was chosen
                fputc('\n', fp);//put newline but the first character from next word is deleted
            }